# How can I config apache mod rewrite?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

My web root is /var/www/test/public, eg：http://www.test.local is rewrite to here,
but there's a folder /var/www/test/documents/ where I store some pictures to let others download. How can I config my apache rewrite mod to allow users to download pictures in this documents folder by a url?
Can anyone help me? Thanks!

Comment: That's great! Thanks!By the way, I find another problem: as my web server has several virtual hosts, and now the /var/www/test/documents can be accessed by example.com/images or test.com/images, how can I solve this problem? Thans!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need mod_rewrite for that. You can use an Alias directive to map that images directory into your document root:

```
Alias /images /var/www/test/documents
      ^--web path   ^---file system path
```

That'd make any request for `example.com/images` be internally redirected to /var/www/test/documents, even though that documents dir is not within your site's webroot.